# How merge tables to selectively add records to a third table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to merge two tables together so that a record containing a 
day of the week is added where no record currently exists. For example, given the following tables:

```
shop_id process_day

1   Mon
1   Tues
1   Wed
1   Thurs
1   Fri
1   Sat
1   Sun
2   Mon
2   Tues
3   


days_of_week

Mon
Tues
Wed
Thurs
Fri
Sat
Sun
```

how can I join them to add days of the week so that the new resulting table looks as follows:

```
shop_id data_process_date
1   Mon
1   Tues
1   Wed
1   Thurs
1   Fri
1   Sat
1   Sun
2   Mon
2   Tues
2   Wed
2   Thurs
2   Fri
2   Sat
2   Sun
3   Mon
3   Tues
3   Wed
3   Thurs
3   Fri
3   Sat
3   Sun
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CROSS JOIN` to get all possible combinations. In a [Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), we can get the unique values of the `shop_id`, and then do a Cartesian product (Cross Join), to get all possible combinations:

```
SELECT 
  dt.shop_id, 
  t2.days_of_week AS date_process_date 
FROM 
(
 SELECT DISTINCT shop_id FROM table1
) AS dt 
CROSS JOIN table2 AS t2
ORDER BY dt1.shop_id
```